# Get current target values while effect executing

Tags: apache-flex, effects, flex-spark

At a certain point in an effects execution i would like to execute some code.

Say for example that i have a move effect on objectA and half way through this effect i want to make objectB disapear.

Is there any functionality built in to the spark effects framework to do this or do i need to implement the effect myself by hand?

Answer (score 0):

Short of using a timer, I don't think you can with the effect library.  However, I recommend you look at [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/); it's an amazing animation library that is fast, efficient and has a lot of really cool options (like what you just said).

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a composite effect like Parallel with a startDelay on the second effect?

```
<s:Parallel>
    <s:Move target="{target1}" xBy="100" duration="1000" />
    <s:Fade target="{target2}" alphaTo="0" startDelay="500" duration="0" />
</s:Parallel>
```